# Have status automatically go from pending to approve

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP I'm trying to build a shop using a template, but it has me going in and manually approve each order. How can I change it so that orders automatically go from pending to approved?

```
<?php
                if($post->post_status == 'pending') : ?>
                    <a title="<?php _e("Approve", 'enginethemes'); ?>" data-action="approve" class="color-green action publish" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a title="<?php _e("Decline", 'enginethemes'); ?>" data-action="decline-mjob-order" class="color-red action decline" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                endif;
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any framework that you haven't mentioned?

I would change the value of $_POST['pending'] to approved before you commit the order to database.